# dbunit schema parameter does not work

Tags: java, maven, dbunit

I have following configuration for dbunit

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>ojdbc6</groupId>
             <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
             <version>1.0</version>
             <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
         </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.com:1521/user</url>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>password</password>
            <format>flat</format>
            <schema>myschemaname</schema>
            <useQualifiedTableNames>true</useQualifiedTableNames> 
            <tables>
                <table>
                    <name>tablename</name>
                </table>
            </tables>
         </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When I run export goal, it fails with sql exception stating that table is not found. However if I change table name from `tablename` to `myschemaname.tablename` and remove `schema` node export works correctly. Even if  I do not remove `schema` node it works correctly, so it just does not fail with `myschemaname.tablename` table name.

What is wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Try set useQualifiedTableNames to false:

```
<useQualifiedTableNames>false</useQualifiedTableNames>
```

Check out the dbunit maven plugin documentation [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dbunit-maven-plugin/export-mojo.html#useQualifiedTableNames).

**UPDATE:**
if you use Oracle 10g, you probably need enable [skipOracleRecycleBinTables](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dbunit-maven-plugin/export-mojo.html#skipOracleRecycleBinTables) as well:

```
<skipOracleRecycleBinTables>true</skipOracleRecycleBinTables>
```

As stated in DBUnit doc [here](http://www.dbunit.org/properties.html):

> **Skip Oracle 10g Recyclebin tables**
>
> Enable or disable the processing of oracle recycle bin tables (tables starting with BIN$). Oracle 10g recyle bin tables may break DbUnit's assumption of tables name uniqueness within a schema since these table are case sensitive. Enable this feature for Oracle 10g databases until the bug in the oracle driver is fixed, which incorrectly reports this system tables to DbUnit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought that `useQualifiedTableNames` forces extending a table name with the schema name. Is it correct?

Comment: @mishanesterenko, according to the documentation, if you set it to true, you need define your <table><name> like mySchema.myTable, just set it to false and try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help.

Comment: This seems that node `schema` does not any impact on the table name resolving.

Comment: I have tried all combinations of `useQualifiedTableNames` and `skipOrgacleRecycleBinTables` and no luck.